# Include another xcode project into my own

Tags: xcode

How can I include a project (is standalone) into my project and launch it from within my own app? What are the requiered steps so that my current project recognizes all the sourcecode from the other project?

Comment: Why not just import the specific files that you need instead of the entire project?

Answer (score 0):

If you are intending to run an application unmodified from another application, you can't do this.  iOS expects you to have one application executable with one entry point and one app delegate.

If you have a library in source form that you would like to include in your project, you can simply drag the files into Xcode while your project is open.

Comment: well what I could do is copy all the sourcefiles manually into my project and make some modifications, but there should be an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

If you drag an Xcode project file into the project navigator sidebar it will be added to the project setup.

You will need to configure import paths and other things in order to access code though.

If you are trying to use 3rd party libraries, I strongly recommend having a look at [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org). It's really easy to set up and manages dependencies with all of their build settings for you.

Comment: the project is a complete standalone app with its own 3rd party libraries. I just wanted to include it into mine.

Comment: What do you want the other project to provide? If you just want access to some of the code from it, then adding the Xcode project file as I described should allow you to import the classes you need.